# Calculating the size / capacity / storage / memory in use by a single post

Tags: database, wordpress, ubuntu, storage

I have a Custom Post Type. Let's use Books. Each book contains a couple images, the description, ...

When I go to import all of the books, I would like to import one, then calculate the space used by this post. Multiply it with some leverage by the total number of books, then increase the servers storage. Before eventually running the full import knowing I have enough space on the server.

I can provide the post ID, have access to the database for queries, can add a plugin, access the Ubuntu ~ Nginx server, have wp installed so can query WordPress from within the CLI.

**Can anyone tell me how I can figure out the space used by a single post?**

Answer (score 0):

Two kinds of "space" are in play.

1. File system space for media (cover images, photos of authors, perhaps, for books). The extra file space you need for those images is about twice the size of the images: WordPress makes a few thumbnails (low-resolution copies) from each one.
2. Table space in your MariaDB / MySQL server. It needs to store the text of each post, plus a bunch of identifying data, plus metadata for each post, plus indexes. If you figure that it will take three times the actual length of the text in the article, you will be plenty safe.

You can find the space used by your posts with this query (which you can use in phpmyadmin).

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME, AVG_ROW_LENGTH, TABLE_ROWS,
       DATA_LENGTH+INDEX_LENGTH TABLESPACE_USED 
  FROM information_schema.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() 
   AND TABLE_NAME LIKE'%_post%';
```

You'll get a result like this:

| TABLE_NAME | AVG_ROW_LENGTH | TABLE_ROWS | TABLESPACE_USED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| wp_postmeta | 345 | 10,659 | 7,372,800 |
| wp_posts | 1,195 | 3,961 | 12,681,216 |

In this result, `TABLESPACE_USED` is the total amount of data, in bytes, used by both data and indexes in the database.  This particular WordPress instance has almost four thousand posts, and an average of two or three metadata items per post.

Run this before you insert some items to your site, then run it after and look at the differences.

The way databases work, you probably won't see anything interesting if you insert just one post and take the difference. Databases have all kinds of partially filled disk blocks, and one insert may just fill a few of them a bit more full. Try inserting 100 or 1000 posts to see a meaningful difference.

And, don't overthink this. Unless you have literally millions of items to insert, you'll find that space (for images and database data both) is not scarce even with the most "budget" hosting service.

Comment: Interesting, I will have a go at this in due course. I still think there might be another approach... Appreciatively, Jason.

Comment: If I were to write a plugin to gather and interpret raw ssd/hard-drive utilization numbers for ops capacity planning purposes, this post outlines how I would do it.   FWIW.

Comment: It's worth a lot, thanks